# how to solve my image adapter error in my application?

Tags: android, image, adapter

hi I am trying to get my arraylist value into my image adapter class but i got error now. i am trying to solve but i don't know.

error line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));
```

error : The method get(String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (int)

my code:
parxmlActivity.java class

```
public class ParxmlActivity extends Activity {

    private String array_spinner[];
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;

    ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet= null;

    ArrayList<String> hltag_List=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Subchild>sltag_List=new ArrayList<Subchild>();

    ArrayList<String> name_List =new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mmimage_List = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mname_List = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mmimage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mvideo_List = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<schild> model_List =new ArrayList<schild>();
    ArrayList<String> mspec_List = new ArrayList<String>();

    Spinner spinner_hltag,spinner_sltag, spinner_path;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_hltag;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_sltag;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_path;

    int hltagPos=0;
    int sltagPos=0;


    Object sdcard;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        spinner_hltag= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner_sltag = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ParxmlActivity.this, tabview.class);
                //intent.putStringArrayListExtra("numbers", mspec_List);
                intent.putExtra("name",model_List.get(position).name);
                //intent.putExtra("name",model_List.get(position).name);


                startActivity(intent);  

            }
        });

        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);


        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);



        try {
            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
            ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our file. */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("mafile.xml")));
            /* Parsing has finished. */

            parsedExampleDataSet =myExampleHandler. myParsedExampleDataSet;

            for (int i = 0; i < parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size(); i++) {
                Log.v("gethltag SIZE ", ""+parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size());
                hltag_List.add(parsedExampleDataSet.getHLTag().get(i));

            }

            sltag_List = parsedExampleDataSet.getSLTag(hltag_List.get(hltagPos));

            for(int i = 0; i < sltag_List.size(); i++) {
                name_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).name);
                path_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).path);

            }
            model_List.clear();     
            model_List = sltag_List.get(sltagPos).model;

            for(int j = 0; j<model_List.size(); j++){
                mmimage_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).imageList);
                mname_List.add(model_List.get(j).name);
                mvideo_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).videoList);
                mmimage.add(model_List.get(j).mimage);
                mspec_List.add(model_List.get(j).spec);

            }




            spinner_hltag.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(ParxmlActivity.this, R.layout.row, hltag_List)); 

            spinner_sltag.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(ParxmlActivity.this, R.layout.row1,name_List)); 


        } catch (Exception e) { 

        }


    }


    }
```

this is my ImageAdapter.class i got error in below code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Bundle path_List;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return path_List.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return imageView;

    }



}
```

Comment: Just remove Bundle path_List line and run application again and let me know what happen..

Comment: i remove now i got path_List cannot be resolved error in two places...

Comment: line: return path_List.size(); and another one is Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));

Comment: In your  ParxmlActivity's field declaration erite something like, private final ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: already i created this arraylist in my parxmlActivity.java class now i want access that array list value in my imageadapter.java class thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get **string values** from `Bundle path_List` instead of `ArrayList<String> path_List` that's why **you got this error**..

Remove this line `Bundle path_List;` from `public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Make a reference to `ArrayList<String> path_List` not to `Bundle path_List`

And try to run again..

**UPDATE:** Also I am assuming your ImageAdapter class in ParxmlActivity..

**Code:** Also if possible make changes in your ImageAdapter class.. something like,

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();
    Activity activity;

public ImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> path_List)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.path_List = path_List;
    }
 ....
```

And in your activity this line should be,

```
 sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,path_List));
```

Comment: 1st see my parxmlActivity.java class i already create pah_List Arryalist and stored value. just now i am trying to get my path_List value only in my image adapter

Answer (score 0):

`public Object get (String key)` will not take int as argument .

so `replace path_List.get(position`) by `path_List.get(String.valueOf(position))` .

one more thing i want to add is bundle is null here , so first insert path  inside it .
might be you forgot to pass it from activity to adapter .

Update :
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((String)path_List.getString.valueOf(position));

Comment: i changed shailendra new error: The method decodeFile(String) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Object)

Comment: same 1st error: The method get(String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: updated . seems you are very new in java . some good tutorial will be good for you to get rid of these basic things